# How to find string pattern in column operations?

Tags: python, regex

Below is the expected output:

[image]

Explanation: I have to write a Python script to read all cells in Modules column and remove pattern up to **`u_< string > (right to left)`** and **`search string in Name column`**, If `string` is present in `Name Column`, Result will be `True` in Result column if not will be empty in result column.

I tried with 're' module, but not able to find the proper solution.

Comment: *If string is present in Name Column* - in any row?

Comment: First i have to check Modules column, then i need to compare with Name column. If Both are same(as per string matching pattern), I need to mark as True.

Comment: on the same row? - `df['Modules'].str.split('_').str[-1] == df['Name']`

Comment: If you want nan - `df.loc[df['Modules'].str.split('_').str[-1] == df['Name'], 'Result'] = True`

Answer (score 0):

Name in Module, Result = **True**

```
df_module['Result'] = df_module.apply(lambda x: x.Name in x.Modules, axis=1)
```